# GoogleDrive list files with pageToken incompleted

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using iOS sdk and REST API,
In my Drive, I have a folder with 599 files in it.
I use the pageToken in the query, with a pageSize of 100 (default).
In return, I've got 100 + 100 + 99 files, total of 299 files returned.
So, I've tried the native GoogleDrive iOS app, I scroll at the bottom of the big folder content, to make sure all files are loaded, then I push "select all" and it says 299 files selected.
So I decide to download this big folder to my desktop, using the web browser, and I received the exact 599 files.
Is there a limit somewhere ??

Comment: I am not aware of such limit, you may have made other mistakes, please post your source codes for folks to review and comment

Comment: Have you tried using the [Try it!](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) to see if you receive the same result? If you received different result, there may be some code implementation that is affecting your query.

Comment: If it is the same kindly check the following pending bug reports : [iOS SDK can't request more than 100 files](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4580) and [files.list returns an incomplete list when using q=" 'FOLDER_ID' in parent "](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4531) that also experience incomplete result, you may want to star to be updated on the development about the issue

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, those 599 files are dummy text files (1ko) I've created to test different types of character sets in the filename.
To do that, I've got those filenames from wikipedia's list of languages. So each filename is a language in its own writing.
So some of them are simple ascii characters, but others are unusual characters.
And it seems to be related to that, because I've created another set of 600 files with basic [a-z] characters, and indeed, I've got the 600 files back from the file list request.